# Como funciona namespaces no C#?

Tags: c#, namespace

Eu estou estudando C# e me deparei com `namespaces`.

Como funciona e quando é aplicado?

Caso possível algum exemplo básico.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## Funções

*Namespaces* são confundidos por muitos programadores. Há dois entendimentos úteis.

Primeiro para **organizar seus tipos logicamente**. É como se você colocasse determinados tipos (classes, estruturas, enumerações, delegações, interfaces, etc.) que são relacionados de alguma forma em uma mesma "caixa". A sintaxe da linguagem dá bem a indicação que é isto que ocorre. Mas é enganosa.

O segundo entendimento é **desambiguar nomes de tipos que parecem ser conflitantes**. Ou seja, você pode ter dois ou mais tipos com o mesmo nome na sua aplicação (dentro do seu projeto ou externamente), desde que eles estejam em *namespaces* diferentes.

## Ele não encapsula nada

Este entendimento mostra que apesar da visão que os programadores têm sobre o *namespace* ser um módulo, uma caixa de tipos (como indica a primeira função), na realidade ele funciona como um sobrenome para para os tipos. Um sobrenome funciona como uma forma de nomear uma família. Assim você pode ter dois `Ricardo`s no mesmo ambiente sem confusão, porque um é `Oliveira` e o outro é `Silva`.

Então quando você cria:

```
namespace Estoque {
    public class FormCadastro { ... }
}
```

Na verdade internamente é criado:

```
public class Estoque.FormCadastro { ... }
```

O *namespace* desparece e dá lugar a um **sobrenome para o tipo**. Então, apesar de ser uma boa ideia ver o *namespace* como uma caixa que agrupam tipos, essa ideia passa uma impressão errada do conceito.

Pense bem, se fosse uma caixa de verdade, você poderia ter essa caixa separada em vários pedaços? Ou pior, você poderia ter a mesma caixa em vários lugares? Fisicamente é impossível. E o *namespace* permite isto. Então ele não é uma caixa, ele é um sobrenome. Você pode ter a mesma família (mesmo sobrenome) separada em vários lugares. Alguns membros estão em um lugar (um arquivo fonte) e outros estão em outro. De fato recomenda-se ter apenas um membro (um tipo) em cada arquivo).

## Sobrenomes compostos

Você pode ter mais de um sobrenome. Por exemplo quando tem um *namespace* `System.Collections`. Você está dizendo que o sobrenome é composto por duas palavras. Você não tem uma família chamada `System` e dentro desta família uma sub-família chamada `Collections`. Algumas pessoas podem entender que colocando um `using System` no seu fonte incluirá todos os tipos do `System.Collections` e esta ideia é errada. São coisas (famílias) independentes. Não há um conceito de árvore de *namespaces*. Já que não são caixas, os *namespaces* não podem estar uns dentro dos outros.

## Economizando digitação

A vantagem de ser considerado algo separado do nome do tipo e não parte integrante é que você pode usar esses tipos sem o sobrenome, desde que indique em que família deve-se procurar pelo membro (pelo tipo). Isto é feito com a diretiva `using`. Mais informações [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16563/101).

A ideia de que o `using` funciona como um `include` não é verdadeira. Pode-se pensar assim para facilitar o entendimento, mas na realidade o mais próximo do `include` que se faz em .NET é incluir um *assembly* no projeto (criar uma referência para ele). Manualmente seria incluir algo assim:

```
<References>
  <Reference
    Name = "Lib1"
    AssemblyName = "Lib1"
    HintPath = "\\BuildServer\Latest\Release\SharedComponent\SomeControl.dll"
  />
</References>
```

## Módulos no .NET

Em C#, ou .NET como um todo, é possível ter o conceito de caixa real. Isto é feito através do *assembly*. Veja mais [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15666/101).

A ideia do include é mais próxima aos pacotes do Java. Embora o `package` do Java é uma conjunção do *assembly* e do *namespace* encontrado no C# e VB.NET. Essas linguagens separam os conceitos.

## Conclusão

É preciso entender o que são agrupamentos lógicos. Isto não é um conceito da linguagem, mas uma forma de organizar seus projetos. Provavelmente você vai querer organizar tudo que faz parte do `Estoque` em um mesmo *namespace*, todos fazem parte da família `Estoque`. Algumas pessoas podem ficar tentadas a agrupar todos os `Forms`s da aplicação em um mesmo *namespace* mas isto normalmente seria um erro. Você está colocando membros estranhos na mesma família só porque eles "exercem a mesma profissão".

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/NameSpaceReference.cs).

Comment: Boa analogia com sobrenomes.

Comment: @Washingtondacosta nem precisei ser muito criativo, porque é exatamente isso que ele é :)

Answer (score 27):

Namespaces servem para duas coisas ao meu ver:

- organizar o código, agrupando classes, estruturas e outros afins
- evitar conflitos de nomes de classes, estruturas, delegates, etc..

### O que significa o namespace

Quando você cria classes e outros dentro de um namespace, na verdade o namespace faz parte do nome daquela classe.

```
namespace EspacoNomes
{
    public class MinhaClasse
    {
    }
}
```

Na verdade o nome completo dessa classe é `EspacoNomes.MinhaClasse`.

**Usando classes sem indicar o nome completo**

O nome completo da classe pode ser reduzido para somente `MinhaClasse` quando se faz uso dos `using`s no topo do arquivo, ou no início do namespace:

```
using EspacoNomes; // faz com que todas as classes dentro do namespace possam
                   // ser referidas somente pelo nome final da classe
```

Também é possível renomear completamente uma classe com um using:

```
using NovoNome = EspacoNomes.MinhaClasse
```

Agora pode-se fazer referência à `EspacoNomes.MinhaClasse` usando-se simplesmente `NovoNome`.

Outra coisa importante é que quando um código está dentro de um namespace, ele pode fazer referência direta a tudo que está diretamente no mesmo namespace. Por exemplo, duas classes dentro do mesmo namespace podem se referir uma à outra usando apenas o nome final da classe.

Comment: Existe alguma coisa parecida para se aplicar em forms? por exemplo caso eu queira separar forms de cadastro, consultas e etc?

Comment: Você poeria usar os próprios `namespaces` para isso. É só alterar o namespace e pronto.

Answer (score 20):

`namespaces` em [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) são conjuntos de identificadores que servem para agrupar funcionalidades comuns. Por exemplo, em um projeto MVC, tenho um `namespace` para modelos (`Models`), um para controladores (`Controllers`) e um para visões (`Views`).

Na declaração de uma classe, quando fazemos uso de outra classe (utilizando a declaração `using`), o uso de `namespaces` é útil porque a inclusão de um `namespace` em `using` faz com que a classe em questão possa ter acesso a todos os ítens implementados naquele `namespace`. No exemplo do MVC, se uso `using MeuProjeto.Controllers` em algum fonte, todas as classes marcadas com o `namespace MeuProjeto.Controllers` estarão acessíveis neste fonte.

Comment: Você está errado sobre os `internal`s... eles são visíveis em todo o assembly, desde que seja por outro código dentro do mesmo assembly.

Comment: Não lembro onde li que `internal` valia apenas dentro do `namespace`, mas você tem razão. Editei a resposta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Melhor dizendo uma namespace é um meio de uma classe, struct, variável ser localizado.

tipo:

```
namespace loc{
  public class usuario : Form { }
}
```

a namespace numa localidade externa:

```
using loc; // a namespace utilizada acima

class Program{
   void Main(){
     usuario u =new usuario(); u.ShowDialog();
   }
}
```

se você quiser utilizar uma classe de uma namespace sem utilizar ela por inteira utiliza-se o código:

```
using Thread = System.Threading.Thread;

class App{
 public App()
{
  Thread.Sleep(100); // em vez de usar System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); / using System.Threading.Thread;
}
}
```