# Como funciona o "namespace" no ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, namespace

Não conheço ASP.NET, mas tive que dar suporte em um código de terceiro muito desorganizado por sinal.

Tenho um arquivo `xxxx.aspx` que esta na pasta `/cp` e tem essas chamadas:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
**<%@ Import Namespace="Sitefeito.Mkrbpg" %>**
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.VisualBasic" %>
```

Também na pasta `/cp` tenho arquivo `yyy.asp` que tem

```
Namespace Sitefeito.Mkrbpg
```

Dentro de uma outra pasta `/cp/vb` tenho os arquivos `zzz.aspx` e outro `www.vb` ambos também com:

```
Namespace Sitefeito.Mkrbpg
```

Sendo assim, qual dos arquivos ele esta chamando?

Visto que eu já deletei os três e ainda assim o código continua funcionando. No entanto, se eu mudar o `Namespace` ele ai ele dar erro.

Comment: Você conhece Java? as `namespace` são para o C# a mesma coisa que os `packages` são para o Java até aonde eu me lembro.

Comment: Conheço um pouco de java sim. E ate onde entendi o namespace era para chamar o yyy.asp pois é o equivalente em path. Sendo que o namespace não tem um path completo.

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade Não são, há uma enorme diferença conceitual entre `namespace`s e `package`s. Em C# o equivalente ao `package`seria o `assembly`.

Comment: @bigown Eu ouvi isso uma vez em uma discussão sobre as diferenças e as equivalências entre C# e Java, mas não pude afirmar, por isso comentei que até aonde eu me lembre era isso. Vou dar uma olhada nos conceitos

Comment: Alias, errei também, porque o `package` não é o mesmo que o `assembly`, afinal ele carrega um conceito de `namespace` junto. Pacote e nomeação dos tipos se confundem no Java. No C# ou VB.Net é que totalmente são separados.

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma das respostas se te ajudou. Nenhuma ajudou? Tem algo na minha resposta que precisaria melhorar para atender 100% ao que você precisa?

Answer (score 13):

Parece que a confusão aqui é sobre a conceituação do que é `namespace`.

Um `namesapace` é um sobrenome para um tipo (uma classe por exemplo). Se você tem uma `namespace X` e um `class Y`. É o mesmo que dizer que você declarou `class X.Y`.

## Import

Quando você colocar o `import X`, você está apenas dizendo ao compilador que ele deve pesquisar por tipos (classes por exemplo) usados no seu código naquele arquivo (tecnicamente em qualquer código que esteja abaixo da diretiva `import`). Então o compilador entende que você usou a classe `Y` no seu código e tem um `import X`. Tudo vai funcionar porque ele encontra a classe, ele tem o nome completo da classe.

Quando vai usar um membro de uma classe pode se referenciar a um método Z como `X.Y.Z()` e não utilizar o `import`. Desta forma fica mais claro que o `namespace` é apenas um sobrenome da classe.

## Namespace não é encapsulamento

Portanto você pode ter repetição de `namespace`s para todo lado no seu software. Ele não compartimenta nada. Em .NET essa compartimentação ocorre através o *assembly*. Que é, grosso modo, o equivalente ao `package` do Java. Na verdade, o `package` também organiza o tal sobrenome do tipo ao mesmo tempo. O sobrenome do tipo é o mesmo do pacote onde ele se encontra.

Um `package` tem *path*, assim como o *assembly*. Mas em .NET isso não importa no código. O *assembly* é inserido no projeto externamente ao código. O C# e o VB.NET separaram o conceito de pacote de códigos e agrupamento de tipos (classes, *enums*, etc).

O `namespace` transcende o `assembly` e são conceitos ortogonais. Efetivamente quando o código é compilado, o `namespace` desaparece e só um tipo com sobrenome consta no código.

## Desambiguação

Se seu código possui a mesma classe em `namespace`s diferentes, você precisa usar o nome completo (até pode usar o `import` para criar um alias de um `namespace` para facilitar).

Mas se você tem a mesma classe no mesmo `namespace`, algum erro deve ocorrer. Tanto que a única forma de ter duas vezes o mesmo nome para uma classe é com a utilização de `partial` que indica que em fontes diferentes você tem a **mesma** classe se complementando. Mas não parece ser o seu caso.

## Assembly X namespace

O fato de haver um *assembly* e um `namespace` com mesmo nome, é apenas coincidência. São coisas bem distintas. O *assembly* é referenciado no projeto (pode ser que o problema esteja aí).

## Seu caso

Se você tirou os `import`s e nenhum problema aconteceu, você não estava usando nenhum tipo contido nos `namespace`s "importados". Se você muda o nome do `namespace` que realmente é necessário, vai dar erro.

É possível que alguns destes arquivos que você diz que têm classes duplicadas nem estejam sendo referenciados no projeto. Pode ser que era lixo, teste, sei lá, que o programador anterior deixou lá sem necessidade.

Se precisar de informações mais específicas, precisamos entender melhor como está estruturado seu projeto e seu código.

Para maiores informações pode ler [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101) e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16563/101) resposta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Segundo a [documentação](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zt9tafza.aspx):

> Namespaces organizam os objetos definidos em um assembly. Módulos (assemblies) podem conter várias namespaces, que por sua vez podem conter outros namespaces. Namespaces evitam a ambigüidade e simplificam as referências ao usar grandes grupos de objetos, como bibliotecas de classe.

Sendo assim, vários arquivos podem conter a mesma namespace, e o arquivo que "é chamado" seria aquele que contem uma classe, contida na namespace, que é utilizada na página em questão.

Comment: Correto meu amigo, mas os arquivos  zzz.aspx, zzz.aspx e www.vb tem o mesmo class e o mesmo namespace sendo assim não sei qual a prioridade que ele dar e o mais estranho é que se eu deletar os três arquivos ele continua a funcionar e já busquei em todo meu projeto e só encontro essas três class nos aquivos que citei

Comment: Tem algo bem errado ai, pois não da para ter mais de uma class com o mesmo nome na mesma namespace. Será que o que está funcionando não está referenciando para uma dll, que seria o website inteiro compilado? Já tentou abrir o projeto em sí e fazer esses testes, ao invez de apenas manipular os arquivos .aspx e .vb ?

Comment: Meu caro ao que parece é isso sim, encontrei aqui uma .dll e .PDB com o mesmo nome do namespace. Como faço para manipular os mesmo???

Comment: Tu não tem acesso ao Projeto dessa dll? Com esse projeto tu conseguiria manipular ela, senão fica mais complicado, mas é possível que programas como o Reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) te ajudem nessa questão.

Comment: Também existe o http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: @bigown conseguir descomplicar e extrair o código fiz a alteração, existe alguma opção para recompilar mais leve do que o visual studio?

Comment: @IagoLeão não muito. Você pode compilar pela linha de comando usando o, eu sei que em C# é o csc.exe (não sei do vb.net, nunca usei, mas está dentro da pasta do .Net dentro do Windows), mas a diferença vai ser bem pequena.