# Como criar uma dll para ser usado no asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

vale ressaltar que não sou programar asp.net muito menos c# ou algo do tipo. Mas tive que dar suporte em um sistema em asp.net que consome um .dll

Precisei fazer uma alteração nesta dll. Conseguir decompilar e fazer a alteração através do [.NetRefletor](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/). Só que não sei como faço para compilar novamente o meu código. A galera fala do [visual studio](http://www.visualstudio.com/), mas a zorra é muito pessado, existe algum software mais leve para que eu possa fazer isso?

Comment: "(...) não sou programar asp.net muito menos c# ou algo do tipo". Infelizmente, a única maneira de se fazer o que você quer é aprender a programar, e programar muito bem, em .NET. Se não quiser usar o Visual Studio, vai ter que desenvolver mais ainda sua habilidade com programação, para utilizar os compiladores via linha de comando.

Answer (score 1):

Iago, não que eu conheça.

Nunca fiz esse processo de decompilação, mas para compilar você precisará do Visual Studio (recomendo o 2012), e realmente ele é pesado, mas não tão quanto outras plataformas de desenvolvimento atuais.

Você irá encontrá-lo aqui [DreamSpark](http://www.dreamspark.com)

Comment: Baseado nesta pergunta e na http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15666/como-funciona-o-namespace-no-asp-net#comment28472_15672, ele parece ter o Visual Studio e acha pesado. Mesmo que não tenha, para quem não vai trabalhar em um projeto por longo período a versão Express (sem custo, limite de tempo ou burocracia) é mais recomendada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15666/como-funciona-o-namespace-no-asp-net#comment28472_15672. Mas o mais importante é que **não é necessário o Visual Studio** para fazer nada em .Net, basta o próprio .Net no computador.

Comment: Os compiladores e todas as ferramentas básicas de C# e VB.Net estão disponíveis nele e são os recursos mais leves que estão disponíveis para compilar alguma aplicação em .Net através da linha de comando.