# Using não utilizados afetam a performance?

Tags: c#, desempenho, namespace, clr

Enquanto desenvolvia, vi que em grande parte das minhas classes continham uma certa quantidade de `using` que não estavam sendo utilizados e me veio a dúvida do título.

Using não utilizado afeta o desempenho da aplicação de alguma forma? É preciso sempre remover os não utilizados ou isso não fará diferença?

Comment: Definitivamente não... afeta na legibilidade do código entretanto.

Comment: Por isso existem ferramentas que retiram todas as diretivas `using` não usadas. Não confundir com o *statement* `using`.

Comment: @bigown: boa observação! Documentação sobre o [statement using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) e sobre a [diretiva using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Entendendo o *using* e o *namespace*

Primeiro vamos deixar claro que existem dois tipos de `using` em C#. Existe o *statement* que é utilizado para finalização de recursos. Veja um pouco mais [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16065/101). E [nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101) também.

Mas você está falando da diretiva do compilador. Está falando de algo que funciona como um alias, uma forma para simplificar o acesso a tipos disponíveis para sua aplicação.

É bom notar que você só pode colocar no `using` os *namespaces* e tipos que estão referenciados no seu projeto. Ou seja, o compilador só vai tentar buscá-los em *assemblys* que estão inclusos no projeto. O *assembly* não precisa estar no projeto mas o compilador não pode procurar em *assemblys* que não tenha nenhuma referência e que estejam disponíveis em algum local acessível a ele.

*Namespaces* na verdade não existem internamente no .NET. O que chamamos de *namespaces* na verdade são sobrenomes para tipos. Veja mais [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15666/101). É só trocar o `import` por `using` já que lá a resposta é sobre VB.NET. O `using` é utilizado apenas para facilitar a legibilidade e eventualmente a digitação do código (mas isso realmente ajuda pouco e não é importante).

Usamos o `using` para indicar ao compilador que os tipos daquele código que não podem ser encontrados neste [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) devem ser procurados em outros escopos do projeto (outros fontes contidos nele ou *assemblys* referenciados no projeto, mas a busca (*lookup*) deve ser feita apenas em determinadas famílias, em determinados sobrenomes, tornando a busca mais rápida e evitando possíveis ambiguidades de tipos.

## Performance

Se um *namespace* é usado apenas para evitar conflitos de nomes, ou seja, ele é parte integrante do nome do tipo, não importa a forma como você escreveu o código, dando um identificador completo, ou deixando o compilador achar o nome completo dele por você, o **código final gerado, o IL, será exatamente o mesmo**.

Retirar um `using` não utilizado, ou seja, que não há tipos contidos nele (com esse sobrenome) sendo usados no código pode **melhorar a performance do compilador** e outras ferramentas de análise sendo usadas no projeto ou solução, já que menos buscas desnecessárias são realizadas.

Por isto existem ferramentas para isto como a existente no Visual Studio, já citada, e do [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) que é um *plugin* considerado obrigatório por muitos programadores C#. Uma ferramenta como o Resharper não se beneficia muito em performance da retirada dos `using`s não utilizados porque ele tenta sempre olhar pela solução como um todo para dar melhores informações e propor melhores ações no código, independente da utilização do `using` (depende de configuração).

Mas não espere grandes ganhos.

## Informações extras

O `using` pode definir um identificador como alias para simplificar a escrita e evitar ambiguidade, inclusive pode determinar tipos genéricos. É uma forma de *typedef* para quem vem do C/C++. Exemplo:

```
using ImageControl = System.Windows.Controls.Image;
using Image = System.Drawing.Image;
using ListString = System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;
ListString lista; // a variável lista será do tipo System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;
ImageControl img1; // img1 será do tipo System.Windows.Controls.Image
Image img2; // img1 será do tipo System.Drawing.Image sem nenhum conflito com o Image acima
```

#### C# 6

Em C# 6 ainda temos uma nova forma de `using` podendo "importar" tipos estáticos. Ou seja, você poderá importar uma classe estática, que na verdade sempre funcionou como se fosse um *namespace* para métodos que não precisam de instância. Exemplo:

```
using static System.Console;
WriteLine("Exemplo");
```

é o mesmo que escrever:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Exemplo");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/NamespaceAlias.cs).

## C# 10

Deve ser possível fazer uma importação global e não precisará usar certos *namespaces* em cada arquivo de código.

Comment: A diretiva `using` só não se compara bem com `typedef` pois não há como fazer o seu escopo ser ampliado para vários arquivos. No C++ se faz isso com um `typedef` dentro de um arquivo header, mas no C# isso não existe (infelizmente =\).

Answer (score 13):

Usings são apenas definições de atalhos para nomenclatura de tipos (class/struct/enum/delegate)... de forma que é possível usar os nomes dos tipos diretamente sob os namespaces indicados pelos usings:

```
using System;

// agora será possível usar a classe String sem especificar o namespace
class Xpto
{
    public String Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Ao remover um using, o que está sendo feito é que o atalho não poderá mais ser usado, mas ainda assim é possível usar o nome completo para se referir ao tipo:

```
// sem o using temos que usar o namespace junto do nome
// mas ainda assim a classe pode ser referenciada
class Xpto
{
    public System.String Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Ambas as formas acima são idênticas no resultado final compilado.

Answer (score 11):

Não afectam a performance do programa, mas no entanto podem afectar a performance das **ferramentas de análise do código**.

Para além disso, deixar usings que não estão a ser utilizados aumenta a dificuldade de leitura do código (que namespaces é que estão a ser usados em concreto?).

Também podem afectar o tempo de compilação dado que o compilador precisa de verificar que os namespaces referenciados não estão a ser efectivamente utilizados.

Edit:
Uma boa forma para os remover com o [VS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514115.aspx)

Comment: Provavelmente, o compilador não verificará se os usings estão ou não sendo utilizados, ao invés disso construirá uma tabela de lookup de nomes de tipos levando em conta todos os usings, o que consome tempo de qualquer forma.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo pelo que entendi o compilador verifica as dependências e durante a compilação remove/ignora as que não estão a ser utilizadas. Tanto que, as dependências não utilizadas não farão parte do IL gerado.

Comment: Ele fará isso de forma independente dos usings. Ou seja, tendo ou não usings, o que define se uma referência a uma biblioteca externa será feita ou não é a utilização de qualquer tipo contido nesta. Na ausência de usings, o código ainda assim pode se referir aos tipos da biblioteca, bastando para isso indicar o nome completo do tipo.

Comment: Você confundiu usings com referências para bibliotecas... o que o compilador remove são referências a bibliotecas não utilizadas e não os usings em si.

Answer (score 9):

Não tem efeito na velocidade de execução, mas pode haver algum efeito na velocidade de compilação, pois há mais *namespaces* para procurar a classe adequada. Eu não me preocuparia muito com isso, entretanto você pode usar o item **Organize Usings** do menu para remover e ordenar as instruções *using*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

Isso não afeta a performance do programa, é a mesma ideia de comentários redundantes nos códigos.

Não faz diferença para o compilador mas pode atrapalhar o programador.

O Máximo que pode acontecer é você diminuir o tempo de compilação do seu programa.