# Usar vários namespaces pesa mais?

Tags: php, desempenho, namespace

Digamos que eu tenha esses *namespaces*:

```
use
    DataTables\Editor,
    DataTables\Editor\Field;
    DataTables\Editor\Format,
    DataTables\Editor\Mjoin,
    DataTables\Editor\Options,
    DataTables\Editor\Upload,
    DataTables\Editor\Validate;
```

Mas eu somente uso realmente 2 deles:

```
use
    DataTables\Editor,
    DataTables\Editor\Field;
    //DataTables\Editor\Format,
    //DataTables\Editor\Mjoin,
    //DataTables\Editor\Options,
    //DataTables\Editor\Upload,
    //DataTables\Editor\Validate;
```

Como visto acima, eu não preciso deles. Então, existe uma perda considerável por deixar os outros 5 *namespaces* mesmo que eu não use?

Comment: Poderia acrescentar na sua pergunta, se isso também pesa para .NET?

Comment: Mais ai iria ficar ampliando a pergunta e ela possivelmente poderia ser fechada. Você pode fazer uma pergunta também aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Para C#: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16563/101

Comment: @bigown O Mais legal é ver que eu mesmo já respondi algo sobre isso. ( e havia esquecido )

Comment: @PauloHDSousa é, eu tinha votado nela

Comment: @MiltonNascimento A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 6):

Na execução do código em si não pesa porque é só uma facilidade para escrever o código sem ter que digitar todo o nome.

Pesa ligeiramente mais para interpretar o código já que tem que fazer uma análise completa do que está ali e que não será usado para nada. Então eu tiraria não só pela performance que é um ganho irrisório, mas para diminuir o tamanho do código e torná-lo um pouco mais fácil de ler e entender, porque o fato de ter algo ali pode passar a ideia que o *namespace* está sendo usado.

E não é só a análise do texto do `use`, no momento de escolher o que usar ele terá que varrer as tabelas de nomes de todos os *namespaces*, então pesa um pouco, não é só o texto para *parsear*.

E ainda tem uma chance de acabar criando um conflito a toa por disponibilizar classes que nem serão usadas, mas pode ter nome igual de algum outro *namespace* com potencial de uso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).