# Referenciar pastas criadas no projeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, visual-studio, namespace

Após eu ir em Project > Add > New Folder, renomear a pasta e colocar classes dentro dela eu não consigo mais referenciar ela em outro arquivo, por exemplo se fosse usar em um *controller*, usaria como sempre usei o comando

```
using nomeProjeto.NomedaPasta
```

Porém, esse "NomedaPasta", não aparece e mesmo colocando sem o auxílio do VS, quando utilizo o *controler* que tem a referencia, é gerado uma exceção dizendo que o `namespace` é invalido.

Já tentei de tudo, fechar e abrir o VS, fechar todas as Abas do VS e abrir de novo, Limpar o arquivo temporário, reiniciar a máquina...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posso estar enganado, mas acho que você não está entendendo bem o que tem que usar neste `using`. Ele se refere a [`namespace`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101), não a projetos e pastas.

Para usar classes que estejam em `nomeProjeto.NomedaPasta`, elas devem estar dentro de um bloco assim:

```
namespace nomeProjeto.NomedaPasta {
    //classes aqui
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/UsingStatic3.cs).

Mas provavelmente não é o que deseja. Não misture `namespaces` com pastas e projetos, são coisas distintas. Esses espaços de nomes devem organizar o código. o Visual Studio organiza o projeto. São coisas que não tem relação direta.

Não posso sugerir um nome mais adequado para o `namespace` porque não conheço a natureza do software e a estrutura do código.

Mais [informações sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15666/101). Outra [pergunta sobre isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16563/101).

Comment: Sobre os conceitos, eu já estava ciente sobre as diferenças, acho que me expressei mal. Porem visualizando a sua resposta e do cigano consegui localizar o problema, quando criava uma classe na pasta,  VS não introduzia automaticamente o namespace...

Comment: Até porque não é função dele fazer isto.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que há uma confusão de conceitos aí.

Isto:

```
using nomeProjeto.NomedaPasta
```

Indica o uso de um ***namespace***, não um diretório.

O que o Visual Studio faz por você (por conveniência, aliás) é, ao criar uma classe em um diretório, designar um *namespace* para a classe baseado no nome do diretório. Tanto que nada impede você de criar uma classe dentro de um diretório com outro *namespace*. Vai funcionar igual.

Comment: Sobre os conceitos, eu já estava ciente sobre as diferenças, acho que me expressei mal. O que estava errado aqui, é que por sla qual motivo, razão circustância, o VS não estava designando automaticamente o namespace em questão, eu alterei manualmente e funcionou perfeitamente!