# Função do namespace além do agrupamento em C#

Tags: java, c#, .net, namespace

Olá eu estava aqui pensando um pouco e me surgiu uma pequena dúvida em relação ao uso do `namespace` em **C#**, ele teria alguma outra função além do agrupamento de "objetos semelhantes" ?

E em uma comparação simples com o **Java** ele teria basicamente a mesma função dos pacotes, é isso mesmo ?

Comment: Também pode ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15666/101

Comment: Eu havia feito esta pergunta,mas como os amigos me indicaram já há uma outra, ao qual a mesma estar respondendo as dúvidas que eu possuía ...