# Por que não é uma boa prática usarmos namespace "std" em C++?

Tags: c++, namespace

Eu estava usando `using namespace (nomeDaBiblioteca);` no meu código e acabei tendo alguns conflitos com outra biblioteca.

Por que esses conflitos acontecem e qual a melhor solução?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

É uma boa prática. Quando é útil e quando se sabe como usar, sabendo que ele tem algumas implicações.

Você pode ter encontrado um problema por uma situação específica.

## O real problema

Talvez a prática ruim já começou na biblioteca que usou nomes iguais aos da biblioteca padrão da linguagem.

Mas nem digo que isto é um problema de fato, afinal *namespaces* foram criados para isto mesmo, para desambiguar nomes iguais de coisas diferentes.

O que há um problema maior é colocar o `using` dentro de um *header* porque aí você inclui o `using` sem ver que ele está lá. Este problema pode ser bem maior. O problema é usar de forma global. Quanto mais local melhor (veja a resposta do Lucas Nunes), usando conscientemente ele não causa problemas.

## A solução

A resposta está correta em dar a solução do nome completo do método incluindo o *namespace*.

Eu diria que é uma questão de gosto para a maioria dos casos se deve usar sempre o nome completo ou não. A maioria dos programadores optam por não usar o nome completo e sim fazer o `using`. Só quando houver um conflito que deveria exigir um nome completo. Não digo o que cada um deve fazer digo apenas para criar uma regra e mantê-la consistente por todo o projeto, ou adotar a regra já existente de um projeto em andamento.

Uma regra interessante nestes casos seria usar o nome completo apenas nas bibliotecas extras e não na `std`, ou o oposto quando a `std` é usada muito pouco.

Se realmente há necessidade de carregar vários *namespaces* que podem ser conflituosos, provavelmente tem algo errado neste código.

Mas se está com medo dos possíveis conflitos, claro, a solução é se precaver mais do que realmente deveria ser necessário. Eu só não acho que é solução para todo mundo.

Há um exemplo mostrando uma possível solução para conflitos:

```
namespace My_lib {

    using namespace His_lib; // everything from His_lib
    using namespace Her_lib; // everything from Her_lib

    using His_lib::String; // resolve potential clash in favor of His_lib
    using Her_lib::Vector; // resolve potential clash in favor of Her_lib

}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/UsingNamespace.cpp).

Fonte: [The C++ Programming Language](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=PSUNAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA409)

## Conclusão

Na própria pergunta do SO *linkada* tem soluções para evitar maiores problemas. E fala sobre os pontos que eu falei aqui.

Na outra pergunta daqui *linkada* mostra o uso no C# que é extremamente incentivado. Claro que no C# as coisas são um pouco mais organizadas que no C++ mas não muda tanto assim.

Não estou pregando aqui que todo mundo deixe de usar nomes completamente qualificados mas eu quase sempre uso o `using` e nunca tive problemas. Óbvio, eu escolho bem as bibliotecas adicionais que eu uso e analiso se ela pode me trazer problemas.

Não vejo a maioria dos programadores preocupados com isto e os códigos deles costumam usar `using`. Há muitas recomendações oficiais do que não é para usar na linguagem e isto não é uma delas. O código fica mais legível desta forma.

## Má prática

O problema é tentar definir como má prática o que na verdade é um inconveniente pontual contornável quando entende todo o funcionamento do que está usando.

Comment: É má prática usar `using` dentro de um cabeçalho. Fora isso eu concordo em não ver problema algum. E em caso de conflito, basta tratar o nome conflitado especialmente usando a notação mais completa, exemplo: `std::string` e `foobar::string`. O recurso `using` muitas vezes torna o código mais legível e deve sim ser usado. +1.

Answer (score 9):

Uma forma menos "agressiva" de utilizar o `using namespace` é fazer dentro de um escopo.
Dessa forma você tem a mesma facilidade, tendo mais controle sobre o namespace.

Por exemplo, você pode usar o `using namespace std` somente dentro de uma função.

```
void hello() {
    using namespace std;

    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    // Várias outras utilizações de std.
}
```

Outro exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    {
        using namespace std;
        cout << "Aqui não precisa de std." << endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Aqui precisa de std." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Você pode rodar no [ideone](http://ideone.com/EW0Zkg).

---

É claro que as regras são as mesmas mesmo para esse caso. Fazer um:

```
using namespace foo;
using namespace bar;
```

Dentro de um determinado escopo terá as mesmas consequências.

Answer (score 2):

O problema que eu enfrentei foi devido a duas bibliotecas que continham o mesmo nome de método e por isso o uso de "using namespace std" não é boa prática, segue abaixo exemplo:

Temos duas bibliotecas

```
using namespace foo;
using namespace bar;
```

Se existirem métodos nas duas bibliotecas cujo o nome seja igual dará conflito, então é melhor que se use `foo::metodo() e bar::metodo()`

Dessa forma, mesmo contendo o mesmo nome de método estamos explicitando de qual lib são elas, logo não gerará conflito.

Outro problema comum é que o std tem vários identificadores que são comuns em outras libs como:

```
list, sort, string, iterator
```

Ou seja, mais um item que poderia facilmente dar conflito em seu código.

Existe um tópico aqui no SOPT explicando como funcionam os namespaces:
[Como funciona namespaces no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11199/como-funciona-namespaces-no-c)

E a referência que eu usei foi a do SOEN:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice