# Existe alguma padrão de organização de projeto para C++?

Tags: c++, namespace, organização-de-projeto

Em Java e ActionScript3.0 usamos os `namespaces` baseados pelo caminho do diretório, eu vejo muito uso de `namespace`, mas não se baseiam pelo caminho da "localização" da classe na pasta.

Busquei muito se havia algum tipo de organização igual tem aquela "recomendação" para PHP, o PSR-4, mas para C++ não encontrei nenhuma recomendação, sei que deve ser algo trivial, mas creio que um mínimo de organização, independente do tamanho da equipe ou ser um projeto pessoal pode ser um bom caminho, no caso o intuito não é usar `namespaces` em todas classes, só em libs isoladas que irei reaproveitar para diversas aplicações.

Existe algo assim para C++, um padrão de projeto "oficial"?

Sendo que não exista, pensei em fazer algo assim:

- `./fornecedor/categoria/foo.h`

  ```
  namespace Fornecedor
  {
      namespace Categoria
      {
          class Foo()
          {
              public:
                  Foo();
          };
      };
  };
  ```
- `./fornecedor/categoria/foo.cpp`

  ```
  #include "foo.h"

  using namespace Fornecedor::Categoria;

  Foo::Foo()
  {
      ...
  }
  ```

Neste exemplo acima:

- O nome da classe é associado ao nome do arquivo
- Os arquivos e pastas sempre são em *lowercase* (letras minúsculas)
- Categoria seria apenas para dividir o uso da classes, por exemplo `fornecedor/matematica/soma.cpp` e `fornecedor/matematica/divisao.cpp`

Isto é apenas uma ideia, seria um bom caminho?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 7):

O *namespace* do C++ [funciona da mesma forma que no C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101). Ou seja, eles são apenas "sobrenomes" para seus membros, nada mais que isso.

Uma das vantagens disso é que eles podem ser compostos. Você pode juntar no mesmo *namespace* coisas completamente isoladas, que não se conhecem. Por isso é um erro tentar usar esse mecanismo da forma apresentada na pergunta. Não que não possa ser feito, mas ele não foi criado para ser usado assim.

É conceitualmente errado, e pode impedir fazer alguma coisa no futuro por ter organizado desta forma. Eu não iria por esse caminho. Não é recomendado oficialmente não fazer assim, mas também não é recomendado fazer.

Note que o próprio [`std`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38435/101) funciona justamente da forma como eu falei. Ele é composto por várias partes independentes. É para ter poucos *namespaces*, não é para fazer igual ao Java. Que por sinal [o C# não copiou porque consideraram essa forma problemática](http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/oreilly/windows/news/hejlsberg_0800.html).

O que o C++ tem de diferente do C# é que este último incentiva a hierarquia de nomes e o C++ não, deve ser o mais simples possível.

Note que os `includes`s é que realmente determinam a organização do que é cada coisa.

E agora [tem os módulos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules), que talvez seja o que deseja. Dependendo de como fizer agora, poderá ter dificuldade em usar o novo recurso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +1 excelente link, estou lendo o `Design Choices`, vai ser um grande avanço.