# Quando usar using namespace em C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, namespace, using

É o seguinte, desde que soube que usar `using namespace std;` era uma má prática deixei de usar using namespace. Só que agora comecei a estudar a biblioteca OpenCV e vejo na documentação dela a usarem `using namespace cv;`. 
E agora fiquei sem saber se uso ou não o `using namespace`. **Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de o usar? Devo usá-lo?**

Comment: Sempre que você ler em algum lugar que um certo recurso de uma linguagem é "má prática", pare e reflita se a fonte onde vc tá lendo é que não é ruim. Se um recurso existe numa linguagem, é porque ele é útil em algum contexto. Qualquer coisa pode ser transformada em má prática. Aliás, eu acho que a sua pergunta é válida, mas seria melhor se fosse focada em algo do tipo: "O que é o `using namespace` no C++, pra que serve, e quando se deve ou não utilizá-lo?".

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38435/porque-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-uma-boa-pr%c3%a1tica-usarmos-namespace-std-em-c

Comment: @LuizVieira Eu acho que é até duplicata, não vejo nada que possa ser dito a mais do que já foi dito lá na outra, a não ser que ele seja mais específico.

Comment: @bigown Pensando bem, acho que você tem razão. Vou votar pra fechar como duplicada.