# O que é o using namespace?

Tags: c++, namespace

Desde o começo da minha aprendizagem em C++ me disseram para utilizar o `namespace std`, para não ficar toda hora utilizando o `std::cout`.

Porém, depois de estudar mais sobre a linguagem, aprendi que o `::` é um operador de escopo, mas e o *namespace*, quais os comportamentos e influencias dele no código?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É uma [diretiva da linguagem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) que determina que você usará um *namespace* naquele código de forma implícita. Este comando realmente evita que fique dando o nome do *namespace* em tudo o que for usar.

O *namespace* é um sobrenome para tipos, funções e outros possíveis membros. É uma forma de evitar nomes iguais fazendo coisas diferentes colidirem. Então tudo o que você for usar tem que escrever o sobrenome seguido de `::` e aí o nome do que vai usar. Isto só não é necessário para o que está no *namespace* global.

Como a maioria dos casos não dá problema e não causa ambiguidade você pode evitar escrever esse sobrenome em cada chamado, você diz que partindo daquele ponto no código até o final do escopo você aceita que aquele sobrenome já é válido.

Tem gente que diz que não é bom fazer isso, mas é exagero. Leia mais sobre em [Por que não é uma boa prática usarmos namespace "std" em C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38435/101).

Se quiser entender mais sobre [*namespaces* tem sobre C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101), o conceito é idêntico.

Pode estar se perguntando se não poderia escrever só `using`. Não pode porque sozinho ele faz outra coisa, ele funciona como um [`alias` para tipos e outras construções da linguagem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) ou para [declarações específicas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).