# Import não está a funcionar

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, namespace

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices
```

> ERROR MESSAGE: "Warning    1   Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Directory.Services' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases."

Por que está a acontecer isto e como resolvo?

Comment: Afinal, é `DirectoryServices` (como no código) ou `Directory.Services` (como na mensagem de erro)?

Comment: É VB mesmo ou VB.Net. Desconeço `imports` em VB.

Comment: E' sem o ponto DirectoryServices. 
Nao sei a diferença srr oO (sou muito novato ainda)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você vai ter que adicionar um referência ao projeto. O fato de colocar no código que você deseja importar não indica onde está o *assembly* que contém este [*namespace*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101).

Tem [documentação que fala sobre este erro](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/namespace-or-type-specified-in-the-project-level-imports-qualifiedelementname?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Instruções básicas para o Visual Studio:

- Abra o Solution Explorer.
- Com o botão direito do *mouse* clique no seu projeto e escolha `Add Reference...`
- Na aba `.NET` procure pelo *assembly* com o mesmo nome do *namespace* que deseja importar e clique em `OK`.

Não é complicado fazer isto mas se você está com dificuldade até para descobrir o nome da linguagem que está usando pode se tornar um fardo muito pesado arrumar isto.

Comment: Nao. Ja esta feito. Obrigado :)

Comment: Estou a tentar usar a funcao GetLocalUsers() e ja pus nas referencias e ainda diz que nao esta declarado

Comment: Ja consegui np :)