# Não consigo uma varíavel de outro namespace

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, namespace

Um projeto é **WebApplication** e o outro é do tipo **Console**:

**"ProjetoTeste" NomeDaSolução**
Estrutura abaixo:

1. Business(Pasta)

   2. BusinessDAL(projeto)

      3. ArquivoDAL.cs
2. Console(projeto)

   3. Business.cs

**//Projeto BusinessDAL, ArquivoDAL.cs**

```
using Console; //Isto não funciona, já tentei com e sem.

namespace BusinessDAL
{
    public class ArquivoDAL
    {   

       public static string caminhos(){  



           string valor =  Console.Caminho; // Nâo funciona 
           string valor =  Console.Business.Caminho; // Nâo funciona 
           string valor =  Caminho; // Nâo funciona 

           return valor;

      }
    }
}
```

**//Projeto Console, arquivo Business.cs**

```
namespace Console
{
  public class Business
    {
        public static string Caminho = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Path").ToString();

       //Isto já foi testado também
        public static string NomeDoProduto
         {
             get { return NomeDoProduto; }
             set { NomeDoProduto = Caminho ; }
         }


    }

}
```

**Mensagem de erro:**
the name 'Console' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Acredito que essa é sua dúvida. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740937/accessing-variables-from-other-namespaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criei dois projetos: ConsoleApp1 e ConsoleApp2.

O que você deve fazer é adicionar a referência do `ConsoleApp2` no projeto `ConsoleApp1` para acessar as variáveis do `ConsoleApp2` no projeto `ConsoleApp1`.

Para isso faça o seguinte:

## 1. Adicione a referência do projeto 2 no projeto 1

Botão direito nas *References*, e selecione *Add Reference*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro de *Projects*, selecione *Solution* e marque o projeto que deseja referenciar e clique em OK:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## 2. Acesse a variável desejada

Feito isso, dentro do projeto 1 você já pode acessar a variável do projeto 2 da seguinte forma:

```
  namespace ConsoleApp1
  {
      public class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              var teste = ConsoleApp2.Teste.Caminho;            
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci de citar esta opção  já foi usada.

Comment: Remove o using e utiliza o que eu falei apenas para acessar a variável.

Comment: Isto também já foi feito...

Comment: Consegui, já vou editar a resposta

Comment: Um projeto é do tipo webapplication e o outro é do tipo console, lembrando que este não é o projeto real apenas coloquei partes ficticias para simular

Comment: Sim, irá funcionar igual. Tu tentou ao menos fazer alguma das coisas mencionadas aqui? Criei um projeto do zero e funcionou. Se eu criar outro do tipo web e outro console vai funcionar também.

Answer (score 2):

Usando `Console.Business.Caminho` funciona. Eu criei um projeto sem configurar nada e deu certo. Só fiz algumas alterações para simplificar a compilação, mas se o seu código é o postado na pergunta não tem como dar errado.

Eu mudaria o nome `Console` porque se estiver usando um `using System` vai dar conflito com a classe `Console` contido nesse *namespace*. Claro que se usar o nome completo do que está acessando funciona, como no código abaixo. Neste caso é possível até eliminar o `using` Console`.

Como está no mesmo projeto não precisa fazer mais nada. Se está em outro projeto e está na mesma solução já é para ter uma referência para este projeto, a não ser que corrompeu algo. Se é um projeto em local separado (não é o que mostra na pergunta) aí precisa [adicionar uma referência no projeto para ela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47310/101) ([com apoio visual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40761/101)).

```
namespace BusinessDAL {
    public class ArquivoDAL {   
        string valor =  Console.Business.Caminho;
        static void Main() => System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!"); //só p/ compilar
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando **ideone**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUjY3U2FmS1IzRlE). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3o2Gsj). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/UsingAmbiguos.cs).

Comment: é porque estou trabalhando em um outro projeto foi feito usando  nomes ficticios com apenas pequenas partes do código, mas agradeço as sugestões.

Comment: Aí a pergunta não está clara. Se você posta uma coisa e está fazendo outra, não temos como saber.

Comment: como disse é ficticio, mas a dúvida é simular um projeto que você utilizou é do tipo webapplication e o outro é do tipo console?

Comment: Então estou achando que é duplicata, já tem várias destas respondidas.