# Qual as vantagens de usar namespaces em Delphi?

Tags: delphi, namespace

A partir da versão 2009 do Delphi (se não me engano) veio os ***namespaces***.
Gostaria de saber, num exemplo simples se possível que ilustre um caso de vantagem, qual seriam as vantagens dos namespaces no Delphi?

Explanando um pouco sobre namespaces, em ***C#*** poderíamos ter três arquivos, contendo o mesmo **`namespace`**:

Arquivo **Contas.cs**:

```cs
namespace Projeto.Forms {
    public class ContasForm : Form {
       ...
    }
}
```

Arquivo **Compras.cs**:

```cs
namespace Projeto.Forms {
    public class ComprasForm : Form {
       ...
    }
}
```

Arquivo **Cliente.cs**:

```cs
namespace Projeto.Forms {
    public class ClienteForm : Form {
       ...
    }
}
```

Em um quarto arquivo, **MainForm.cs**, eu teria acessa às três classes apenas por referências ***`Projeto.Forms`***:

```cs
using Projeto.Forms;

namespace Projeto {
    public class ContasForm : Form {
       private ContasForm contasForm;
       private ComprasForm comprasForm;
       private ClienteForm clienteForm;
    }
}
```

Já em **Delphi** isso não ocorre:

Arquivo **Projeto.Forms.Contas.pas**:

```pascal
unit Projeto.Forms.Contas;
interface
uses ...
type
  TContasForm = class(Form)
  ...
```

Arquivo **Projeto.Forms.Compras.pas**:

```pascal
unit Projeto.Forms.Compras;
interface
uses ...
type
  TComprasForm = class(Form)
  ...
```

Arquivo **Projeto.Forms.Cliente.pas**:

```pascal
unit Projeto.Forms.Cliente;
interface
uses ...
type
  TClienteForm = class(Form)
  ...
```

Enfim, ao querer referenciá-las em **Projeto.Forms.MainForm** precido fazer da seguinte maneira:

```pascal
unit Projeto.Forms.MainForm;
interface
uses Projeto.Forms.Contas, Projeto.Forms.Compras, Projeto.Forms.Cliente;
type
  TMainForm = class(Form)
  ...
```

**Não** é possível fazer algo como `uses Projeto.Forms;` e a partir dai ter acesso às três classes. Muito menos é permitido em Delphi ter mais de um arquivo com o mesmo nome.

**O único meio que vi de ter tal benefício seria manipulando**. Exemplo:

Criar mais uma ***unit*** com o nome **Projeto.Forms.pas**:

```pascal
unit Projeto.Forms;
interface
type
  TContasForm = Projeto.Forms.Contas.TContasForm;
  TComprasForm = Projeto.Forms.Compras.TComprasForm;
  TClienteForm = Projeto.Forms.Cliente.TClienteForm;
...
```

E então fazer a referência como havia citado, `uses Projeto.Forms;` e a partir dai ter então acesso às três classes.

Bom, não sei se isso teria consequências e, claro, foi apenas para ilustrar.

Diante disso, pergunto: **Qual as vantagens em utilizar namespaces em Delphi?**

Peço um pequeno exemplo só para ilustrar.
Grato!

Comment: Esta pergunta é específica de C# mas o conceito é o mesmo ou muito semelhante: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11199/como-funciona-namespaces-no-c

Comment: @Caffé, no ***Delphi*** acho que não dá para dizer que ***namespaces*** trazem diretamente a mesma utilidade/funcionalidade.

Comment: Qual seria a diferença entre namespaces Delphi e namespaces C#?

Comment: @Caffé, rapaz, pior que a única coisa que consigo pensar agora é que não consigo ter o mesmo ***namespace*** em mais de um arquivo. A não ser que eu manipule, exemplo: em **`Modelos.Usuario`** eu fazer **`type TTipoAcesso = Modelos.Usuario.TipoAcesso.TTipoAcesso;`**. Então, em Java e C#, por exemplo, em mais de um arquivo você consegue ter ***namespaces*** iguais e com isso criar um "**pacote**" de classes/tipos.

Comment: Por arquivo você se refere *packages* ou *units*? Ter o mesmo namespace para diferentes units é justamente a função do namespace, ou não seria um namespace mas apenas uma unit com nome grande. Quanto a declarar o mesmo namespace em diferentes packages (diferentes arquivos BPL), faz uns anos que não uso Delphi e nem tenho nenhum pra verificar, mas não vejo nenhum motivo para não poder fazê-lo. Você tentou?

Comment: @Caffé, pelas minhas tentativas, dá apenas para ter um ***namespace*** por ***unit***, já que o arquivo tem que ter o mesmo nome da ***unit***. Então, sim, é apenas um arquivo com nome grande. Exemplo: ***`Projeto.Forms.MainForm.pas`***. Não me referi a nada sobre ***packages*** ainda.

Comment: Não, não é apenas um arquivo com nome grande. É um namespace de fato, com todos ou muitos dos benefícios daquelas respostas em C# que eu linkei no meu primeiro comentário. Veja, em *Projeto.Forms.MainForm.pas*, o namespace é *Projeto.Forms*, e nele eu posso ter quantas units eu quiser: *Projeto.Forms.Contas.pas*, *Projeto.Forms.Compras.pas*, *Projeto.Forms.Cliente.pas*...

Comment: @Caffé, se eu fosse fazer uso delas em uma outra unit, exemplo na ***`Projeto.Forms.MainForm.pas`*** eu teria que adicionar: ***`uses Projeto.Forms.Compras, Projeto.Forms.Cliente, Projeto.Forms.Contas;`***. Ou seja, arquivo por arquivo da mesma forma que faria: ***`uses UntContasForm, UntComprasForm, UntClienteForm;`***. Não dá para adicionar apenas ***`uses Projeto.Forms;`*** e a partir dai poder ter acesso à todas as classes dos três arquivos (***`TClienteForm, TComprasForm, TContasForm`***). Elucidando que estou falando de três arquivos e cada um contendo uma classe, para fazer sentido.

Comment: Com esse ultimo comentário e a melhora da pergunta eu entendi o seu ponto. Enquanto em C# os tipos são agrupados logicamente em um namespace, em Delphi os tipos são agrupados em uma unit, e os namespaces não são agrupamentos de tipos mas sim agrupamentos de units. Mais tarde eu posto uma resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Vantagens de usar namespaces em Delphi

> Namespaces em Delphi têm o objetivo de organizar units e tipos de maneira lógica.
>
> Namespaces servem ainda para oferecer um identificador único global para um tipo ou unit, de modo que podemos ter mais de um tipo ou unit com o mesmo nome, no mesmo projeto.

Em um sistema grande, não é incomum que units ou tipos diferentes, de diferentes contextos, tenham naturalmente o mesmo nome.

Por exemplo, um produto no estoque pode ser uma entidade distinta do produto no front-end de vendas (ver *DDD - bounded context*). Namespaces nos permitem de fato chamar ambas as entidades de "Produto", com diferentes namespaces, proporcionando uma nomenclatura mais expressiva e mais próxima do negócio, sem ter que forjar prefixos e sufixos para diferenciar units e tipos de diferentes contextos.

Além disso, há mais clareza em chamar uma unit de `Business.Estoque.Produto` do que `BusinessProdutoEstoque`.

## Diferenças entre namespaces Delphi e namespaces C Sharp

Uma diferença importante entre  namespaces C# e namespaces Delphi é que em C# eles agrupam tipos, e em Delphi eles agrupam units e as units é que agrupam tipos (cada unit é um arquivo de código fonte).

Então, em C#, para trazer para o contexto todos os tipos de um namespace, fazemos assim:

```
using Business.Estoque.Produto;
```

Agora, todos os tipos deste namespace que estiverem referenciados pelo projeto estarão imediatamente disponíveis no contexto.

Em Delphi, o comando acima (seria *uses* em vez de *using*) estaria referenciando a unit *Business.Estoque.Produto* do namespace *Business.Estoque*, trazendo para o contexto todos os tipos declarados nesta unit.

## Semelhança entre namespaces Delphi e namespaces Java

Se no projeto a prática é declarar apenas um único tipo público em cada arquivo, neste aspecto namespaces Delphi são mais semelhantes a namespaces Java (onde são chamados de *packages*), pois em Java o arquivo de código fonte tem o nome da classe pública contida nele, e o padrão é referenciar não um namespace de modo a trazer todos os seus tipos para o contexto, mas sim referenciar cada uma das classes que se deseja trazer para o contexto.

Em Java, o comando `import Business.Estoque.Produto` traz para o contexto apenas a classe *Produto*, tal qual em Delphi estaria trazendo apenas, digamos, uma classe chamada *TProduto* (contida na unit *Produto*).

Aqui, Java tem um recurso que o Delphi não tem. Em Java há a opção de trazer para o contexto todos os tipos do namespace de uma só vez:

```
import Business.Estoque.*;
```

No comando acima, não apenas a tal classe *Produto* mas também todas as classes do namespace *Business.Estoque* estarão disponíveis no contexto. Delphi não tem este recurso, então cada unit do namespace *Business.Estoque* teria que ser referenciada explicitamente, exemplo:

```
uses Business.Estoque.Produto, Business.Estoque.Produto.Categoria,
    Business.Estoque.Inventario;
```

## Conclusão

Namespaces em Delphi tem o mesmo objetivo que em C# ou Java: organizar logicamente o projeto, com o benefício de poder ter identificadores únicos globais para tipos ou units com nomes iguais.

A diferença mais importante é que enquanto em C# ou Java um namespace (em java, *package*) agrupa tipos, em Delphi um namespace agrupa units e as units agrupam tipos.

Em Java, é comum a prática de referenciar explicitamente cada tipo, mas também é possível referenciar de uma vez todos os tipos de um namespace usando o coringa *. Em Delphi a única opção é referenciar explicitamente cada unit.

Apesar de não simplificar a referência a tipos no contexto (não permitir referenciar de uma vez tipos contidos em diversas units), namespaces em Delphi ainda oferecem a vantagem de organizar logicamente o projeto, permitindo nomes mais expressivos para units e tipos.

Por exemplo, em vez de ter no meu código units e tipos com nomes como `CategoriaCliente`, `CategoriaProduto`, `CategoriaFrete`... Eu posso ter `Vendas.Cliente.Categoria`, `Estoque.Produto.Categoria`, `Transporte.Frete.Categoria`.

Comment: Poxa, ficou uma resposta muito legal!! =D Obrigado!