# Diferença de uso de pacotes no Delphi/Lazarus e no Java

Tags: java, delphi, lazarus

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença de uso dos pacotes em projetos *Java* para uso de pacotes em projetos *Delphi/Lazarus*?

No *Java* pelo que sei se trata de separar as classes em pastas as quais a existência da mesma dentro daquele contexto faça sentido.
 Mas no *Delphi/Lazarus* encontrei algumas opiniões mistas aonde em alguns lugares diziam que os pacotes seriam como módulos reutilizáveis além de alguns lugares nem mostrarem o uso dos mesmos, gostaria de saber a opinião de alguém que sabe dos 2 mundos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em *Java* seu conceito está correto.
Em *Delphi* o uso de pacotes ou `Packages` serve mais especificamente para modularizar um sistema. Porém a organização de classes pode ser feita nesses pacotes assim como é feita em Java. Lembrando sempre que é possível trabalhar com Orientação a objetos em Delphi assim como em *Java*. Infelizmente muitos *Delphianos* usam a ferramenta da maneira incorreta (apenas *procedural*), e isso acaba denegrindo a imagem do *Delphi* e de bons *Delphianos*.
Há vários benefícios em se usar `packages` no *Delphi*.
Podem ser consultados [aqui](https://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/89987-artigo-pacotes-em-delphi-modulos/).

Comment: Muito obrigado por responder, é que na aplicação a qual pretendo fazer tem cerca de 210 models e na minha cabeça que está vindo do Java não separar isso seria uma transgressão sem perdão kkkk

Answer (score 1):

Realmente, em Delphi, **normalmente** packages são criados para serem reutilizados. Packages são tratados como um framework.

Isso não significa que você não pode modularizar seu sistema utilizando packages se desejar. Mas se quiser separar classes e módulos, você não precisa criar um package. 
Pode fazer usando [Unit Scope Names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unit_Scope_Names) e [Unit Namespaces](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Namespaces_with_Delphi).

Note que o funcionamento é um [pouco diferente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68989/2652) de outras linguagens.

Comment: Muito bom, sua reposta foi bem informativa obrigado, ou seja mesmo sem criar pacotes é possível ter unidades associadas a um contexto em comum, pior que mesmo entrando nessa linguagem agora acredito que poucas pessoas tenham este cuidado

Comment: @William.Andrade Se pegar uma biblioteca como Spring4D verá que é muito utilizado. Tudo depende do contexto e do tamanho do projeto que está trabalhando.