# Por que alguns métodos tem ' :: '

Tags: ruby, sintaxe, namespace, perl

Por que alguns métodos como por exemplo do Perl ou Ruby: `Net::FTP`, tem esses dois pontos; como é a construção dos métodos dessa classe e por que é criada desta forma (com essa sintaxe) e não da forma cmumente utilizada por bibliotecas atuais: `HTTParty.get()`, `requests.get()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto nada tem a ver com método e sim com a classe e o seu *namespace*. `FTP` é a classe e nela conterá métodos. `Net` é apenas o sobrenome desta classe. *Namespaces* são como módulos que contém classe, mas não exatamente. Em algumas linguagens ele se confunde com um pacote de classes que tem um conceito ligeiramente diferente, a maneira exata de cada linguagem deve ser vista em sua documentação.

Tem uma explicação de [Como funciona namespaces no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101). A linguagem escolheu usar o ponto para *namespaces* também, mas a ideia é a mesma.

Comment: Obrigado, já tinha visto `namespace` simples em código C++ pela internet porém não sabia da ligação que tu apontou.