# Tem algo parecido com os namespaces do C# em Java?

Tags: java, namespace, import

Notei o tamanho do comando para colocar uma mensagem na tela em Java, queria saber se tem como diminuir? Como em C# que o programador coloca a palavra `using` "namespace"; e pode usar o comando "encurtado".

Ex.: para imprimir o Olá S seria algo como:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Olá S"); //sem adicionar o using System
```

Já com o `using System` seria:

```
Console.WriteLine("Olá S");
```

Isso em C#, como é em Java? Teria como fazer algo parecido para o programador colocar apenas `println("Olá S")`?

Comment: Você tem o mesmo comportamento usando  a palavra static depois de import, ex.: `import static java.lang.System.*;`, daria para usar depois assim: `out.println("Olá")`

Comment: Poderia explicar um pouco sobre essa declaração ou passar algum artigo sobre isso? A explicação seria porque eu devo usar o static depois do import, porque não posso usar só o System e para que serve o * ali no final é para selecionar todos os tipos desse pacote?

Comment: [Aqui](http://blog.alura.com.br/como-fazer-um-import-static-em-java/) um artigo que explica um pouco do static import

Comment: O motivo de você precisar usar out.println é que o método println não está dentro de System, é um método da classe PrintStream, o atributo out é um atribuito do tipo PrintStream que está na classe System, por isso a necessidade de chamar out.println

Comment: Ah, esqueci de falar, o * no final importa tudo o que tem naquele pacote ou todos atributos de uma classe quando usado com o static

Comment: Você poderia pensar em usar `import static java.io.PrintStream.*;` para usar somente o `println()` sem precisar chamar o `out` antes, mas só vai funcionar se o método for `static`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depende do que chama parecido. Java tem *packages*, que pode ser confundido como algo parecido (de fato ele contém *também* o conceito de *namespace*), afinal eles colocam um nome na frente do tipos. Em Java você tem:

```
System.out.println()
```

[C# usa o *namespace* como um sobrenome para o tipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101), mais nada além disso. Ele separa em pacotes chamados *assemblies*. Para o Java o pacote é o seu *namespace*, por isso é diferente em vários aspectos.

Você ainda pode fazer isto em C#:

```
using static System.Console;

WriteLine("Olá Mundo");
```

Em Java tem uma diferença semântica importante porque em C# apenas usamos o `using` como um encurtador para não precisar usar o nome completo do tipo, em Java o que se faz é um `import` do pacote para ele ficar disponível para uso, o nome nada tem a ver com isso. O Java faz alguns `import`s automáticos para você poder usar os tipos mais importantes.

Note que em um simples "Hello World" em Java está usando a **classe** `System` e não o pacote ou espaço de nomes `System`. É completamente diferente de C#. Veja a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). Ela faz parte do *package* [`java.lang`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) que é importado automaticamente em toda aplicação (deve ter alguma configuração para evitar isso). Na verdade o mecanismo exato faz parte de [outra classe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#out).

Se desejar não usar o nome completo tem que fazer igual ao exemplo que citei para o C# (mas ainda é menos conveniente):

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

out.println("olá");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/ImportSystem.java).

Comment: Esses imports podem ser considerados como os cabeçalhos em C?

Comment: Esse menos coveniente tem algo haver com o paradigma?

Comment: Está falando de C/C+? Não exatamente, mas lembra um pouco, porque aos tais *headers* na verdade são *includes*, eles só enfiam um texto ali e boa, o `import` tem mais semântica, é um mecanismo mais sofisticado. E o jeito menos conveniente é só porque Java nunca foi muito fã de facilitar a vida do programador. C# tem um mecanismo idêntico, mas tem uma abstração que torna mais conveniente. Se eu fosse programador Java criar essa abstração e usar em todos os meus sistemas seria a primeira coisa que eu faria. Olha: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,748bde83a8b838d8