# Como criar funções com hierarquia? Ex Console>Error>WriteLine()

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Minha pergunta pode parecer confusa então vou explicar.

Imagine que eu tenho três classe: `Program`, `Controle.cs`, `Volume.cs`.

**class Program**

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleAppPOO
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Controle.Ligar();
        }
    }
}
```

**Controle**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleAppPOO
{
    public static class Controle
    {
        public static void Ligar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ligador!");
        }
        public static void Desligar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Desligado!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Volume**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleAppPOO
{
    class Volume
    {
        public static void Aumentar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Aumentaro Volume!");
        }
        public static void Reduzir()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reduzio o Volume!");
        }
    }
}
```

Eu organizei a minha ideia nessas três classes para demostrar o que de fato eu desejo fazer. O meu desejo é poder na class Program poder chamar os métodos de volume que deveria está a baixo do Controle.

**Exemplo:**

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleAppPOO
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Controle.Ligar();
            Controle.Volume.Aumentar();
        }
    }
}
```

O que eu quis falar com relação hierarquia é justamente como se fosse uma arvore de arquivo de uma pasta.

```
|+ Controle
|  -> Ligar()
|  -> Desligar()
|   + Volume
|     -> Aumentar()
|     -> Reduzir()
|
```

A própria linguagem de programação já possui essa característica de árvore que eu desejo implementar. Um exemplo simples disso:

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("text");
Console.Error.WriteLine("text");
Console.Error.FormatProvider.ToString();
```

E então, como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 5):

## Versão curta

Você precisa colocar os objetos dentro da hierarquia desejada para ter esse efeito. Há duas formas de se fazer isso, ou através de namespaces ou através de composição de objetos mesmo.

Usando a composição de objetos, bastaria declarar as propriedades da maneira que você quer acessar, **[como mostro nesse exemplo do dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OQU7yc)**. Tem alguns problemas com esse código, então falo um pouco mais sobre isso a seguir.

Usando a hierarquia de namespace, você poderia declarar o tipo `Volume` dentro do `Controle`, **[como pode ver aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/phjlGN)**, mas também há problemas nesse caso específico.

O uso do `static` no seu exemplo me parece equivocado. Assim como a própria composição sugerida, de acessar o objeto `Volume` através do `Controle`. Como o `Controle` usa o `Volume`, é responsabilidade do próprio `Controle` saber e não quem vai utilizá-lo.

Uma pequena melhoria seria encapsular o volume dentro do controle e expor somente a ação de controlar o volume. Assim:

```
class Controle
{
    Volume volume;

    public Controle()
    {
        volume = new Volume();
    }

    public void AumentarVolume()
    {
        volume.Aumentar();
    }
}
```

**[Veja esse exemplo também](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KZ8YrH)**

## Um pouco mais sobre o assunto

Posso não ter entendido corretamente a sua intenção, mas caso eu tenha entendido você levar em consideração alguns outros conceitos da orientação a objetos.

Então vou separar em tópicos os que acredito que estão relacionados ao exemplo que você expôs:

#### Classes e Objetos

Na orientação a objetos, uma classe define um tipo que representa de maneira abstrata um conceito de qualquer coisa - material ou não.

Seguindo o seu exemplo, imaginando que estamos falando de um controle de TV, poderíamos ter:

1. Classe que abstrai a TV
2. Classe que abstrai o controle (que possi vários comandos)
3. Classe que abstrai o comando que seria enviado pelo `Controle` (no seu exemplo, `Volume`)
4. Classe que abstrai a interação do controle com a TV (no seu exemplo, `Program`)

Os objetos são o que torna o uso dessa abstração possível. Uma vez definida a abstração `Controle`, por exemplo, para usá-lo será necessário antes criar uma representação 'material' dessa abstração. Na orientação a objetos essa representação é dada através de uma instância de `Controle` (`Controle meuControle = new Controle();`).

Trazendo para o mundo real, a classe é como se fosse o manual do controle, que define tudo que aquele tipo de controle faz. O controle específico da sua TV é uma instância daquela definição de controle.

#### Propriedades, campos e métodos

As classes podem também definir propriedades, campos e métodos (entre outros elementos), que auxiliam no controle do objeto ou representam a sua composição.

Segundo a intenção demonstrada, para acessar o `Volume` a partir do controle - cegamente, não considerando outras questões conceituais - você teria 3 opções:

1. Declarar o `Volume` como uma propriedade do objeto `Controle`
2. Declarar o `Volume` como uma propriedade/campo estático da classe `Controle` (não seria uma prática saudável nesse contexto)
3. Declarar o `Volume` no namespace `Controle` (também não seria saudável)

De qualquer uma dessas maneiras você poderia obter o resultado desejado, mas há maneiras melhores de se fazer.

[Veja um pouco mais sobre Propriedades e campos nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/133931/78713)

#### Classes, propriedades e métodos *static*

Essencialmente quando falamos em elementos estáticos, significa dizer que para que aquele elemento seja usado não é necessário existir uma instância do objeto, pois os elementos estáticos não atuam na própria instância do objeto.

[Essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/78713) trata desse assunto profundamente. Recomendo consultá-la.

#### Namespace

A outra forma mencionada é usar o `Namespace`. [Entre as utilidades do Namespace](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/78713) podemos destacar a contextualização de determinada abstração. Essa contextualização ajuda a restringir o escopo da solução apresentada na classe.

Por exemplo, supondo que estivéssemos desenvolvendo estratégias para o fantasma do jogo pacman encontrar o bonequinho. Entre outras, poderiamos definir dois algoritmos de estratégia: 1) perseguir pelo caminho que o pacman fez ou 2) tentar presumir qual a posição do pacman - baseado na localização, velocidade e direção atual dos elementos - quando o fantasma o alcançar.

Uma forma de organizar a classe que fornece esse algoritmo seria os namespaces:

```
namespace Pacman.Game.Gost.Strategies
{
    class PersuitPath
    {
        // some implementation
    }
}
```

ou

```
namespace Pacman.Game.Gost.Strategies
{
    class EstimatePosition
    {
        // some implementation
    }
}
```

Assim, o acesso a essas classes seria através do namespace `var estrategia = new Pacman.Game.Gost.Strategies.PersuitPath();`. Acontece que as vezes declaramos o namespace no `using` e usamos somente a terminologia do elemento dentro daquele namespace:

```
using Pacman.Game.Gost.Strategies;

namespace Pacman.Game
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var estrategia = new PersuitPath();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Abstração

O núcleo conceitual da orientação a objeto é a abstração do mundo real. Pensar no programa e seu comportamente como uma analogia do mundo real contribui na fidedignidade das soluções.

Essa abstração pode se dar em diversos níveis (mais concretos ou mais abstratos) e isso possibilita a reutilização de soluções. No seu exemplo, se a solução for construída segundo o raciocínio, Seria difícil e confuso (para dizer o mínio) usar a classe `Controle` para controlar um `Aeromodelo`, por exemplo, pois `Volume` não faz sentido para ele.

Mais do que isso, Seria possível chamar o método `Aumentar` ou `Diminuir` do `Volume` sem antes chamar o método `Ligar` do `Controle`?

São exemplos de regras do mundo real que deveriam compor o seu modelo abstrato.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

No paradigma de POO, criar hierarquia significa uma classe Filha herdar de uma classe Pai. Mas acredito que o seu exemplo não precise de hierarquia, e sim de melhor Modelagem de Domínio apenas. Como o Diego citou, a classe Controle poderia ter uma propriedade Volume, desde que isso faça sentido para o Domínio do seu sistema.

Recomendo estudar DDD para entender do que modelagem de domínio se trata. Em linhas bem superficiais, seria uma forma de pensar suas classes para que elas representem da melhor maneira as Entidades do seu sistema, isto é, representações de coisas da vida real que seu sistema aborda.